# Computing $\mathbb{P}(X=Y)$ for a joint discrete probability distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> **Problem.** Let $(X,Y)$ be a random discrete vector with probability function given as:
>
> $$ \mathbb{P}(X=x, Y=y) = \frac{\lambda^y e^{-2\lambda}}{x!(y-x)!}\mathbb{I}_{\{0,...,y\}}(x)\mathbb{I}_{\mathbb{N}}(y), \qquad \lambda >0$$
>
> Calculate $\mathbb{P}(X=Y)$

My first attempt was:

As indicator functions are zero for $y \notin \mathbb{N}$ or $x \notin \{0,..,y\}$, both takes one only when $y \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in \{0,..,y\}$, so for this case:

$$ \mathbb{P}(X=x, Y=y) = \frac{\lambda^ye^{-2\lambda}}{x!(y-x)!} $$

As $x = 0 \; \lor x= y \; \lor \; 0<x<y$, for the two first cases,

$$ F_{X}(x) = \lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\lambda^ye^{-2\lambda}}{y!} = e^{-2\lambda}\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\lambda^y}{y!} $$

Therefore, $y \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\lambda >0 \implies \lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\lambda^y}{y!} = 0$. $F_{X}(x) = 0$ for $x=y$, then $f_{X}(x) = 0$ too?

---

Then, with Michh comment, I went for:

$$ f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{\lambda^{y}e^{-2\lambda}}{x!(y-x)!}, & y \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } 0 \leq x\leq y\\ 
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$

So,

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X=Y)
&= \sum_{x \in \mathbb{N}} f(x,x)
= \sum_{x \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{\lambda^{x}e^{-2\lambda}}{x!}
= e^{-2\lambda}\sum_{x \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{\lambda^{x}}{x!} \\
&= e^{-2\lambda}\sum_{x = 0}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^{x}}{x!}
= e^{-2\lambda}e^{\lambda}
= \boxed{ e^{-\lambda} }
\end{align*}

Comment: Hint: start again using the fact that $\mathbb{P}(X=Y) = \sum_{x \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{P}(X=x, Y=x)$.

Comment: @Michh can you confirm the answer to this is $e^{-\lambda}$? Also, now I what to check on the conditional distribution for X as Y= y, and $y \in \mathbb{N}$, so I must go with $\mathbb{P}(Y=y) = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X=x,Y=y)$, right?

Comment: You can edit the question to share your attempt!

Comment: It looks correct to me. Just a tiny detail: the joint "density" $f(x,y)$ is equal to $\lambda^y e^{-2\lambda}/x!(y-x)!$ if $0\leq x \leq y$, and is zero otherwise. (so you're missing the condition on $y$)

Comment: For the conditional distribution you need $\mathbb{P}(X=x|Y=y)$. First question is which values of $x$ are possible? Then you can use Bayes formula which requires you to compute $\mathbb{P}(Y=y)$ with the formula you gave.

Comment: @Michh Thank you so much! I think I can continue from here :)

Comment: Ignoring the fact that your computation of $F_X(x)$ is flawed, why are you even considering $F_X$ in the first place when you can compute $\mathbb{P}(X=Y)$ directly from the given joint PMF?

Comment: @SangchulLee guess I was overwhelmed with other questions too and did not pay attention to the fact that is a discrete vector, so that I can easily sum for the case x is equal y, I just needed to see it clearly, that is why I asked for a hint

Comment: Ah that makes sense, thanks for clarification. Also, your new solution looks good.